# Counter-example to graph degree theorem

Tags: graph-theory

It is well known that a graph admits an Euler circuit if and only if the graph is connected an all degrees are even. I have even written the proof myself. So why is the graph below not a counter-example?? A circuit starting from the center leg and going counter clockwise is an euler circuit but there are two vertices of degree 3.

[see the figure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XD2gs.png)

Comment: The definition of Euler circuit I was given is a closed trail which passes every edge. Label the vertices ccw from the top-right vertex. Then $(35),(51),(12),(23),(34),(45),(53 = 35)$ is a closed trail which passes through every edge.

Comment: counter-clockwise

Comment: yes you are completely right, oops!

Comment: I am using my professor's lecture notes. This is quite confusing as in a comment to the answer below a user posted a different definition of a closed trail. In turn, trails are (usually) defined as walks without repeats, which as far as I know are defined in terms of edges only. Interspersing the vertices seems like an odd and contrived definition that doesn't match up with other sources I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: I misinterpreted the way you described the path, what you described was an Euler trail, as you hit every edge but do not end on the same vertex you start at! An Euler circuit requires you start and end at the same place.**

In the image you provided you say that rotating counter clockwise around the graph is an Euler circuit, however that would be incorrect. While doing so will hit every point on the graph once before returning to the starting point, it does not cover that middle edge that runs in the center! This makes your circuit a *Hamiltonian Circuit*, not an Euler circuit.

Your proof and intuition is correct, no Euler circuit exists because not all degrees are even, however there does exist an Euler trail, in which you hit every edge exactly once, but do not return back to your original starting point. Can you find it?

Comment: Oh I see. There is no way to return to the vertex label 3 (in a comment) without going over the middle edge again. I believe the definition I was working with was incomplete. Thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Actually, I have a lingering question. Is an Euler circuit then a sequence of vertices or a sequence of edges? I understood it to be a sequences of edges, where the first and last edge are the same, I had no notion of starting and ending at the same vertex since they just don't matter, they may or may not be repeated and I don't pick the 'front' vertex of an edge to be my starting point or anything like that.

Comment: My knowledge of graph theory is limited, so take this with a grain of salt, but I would say that it is a sequence of verticies that traverses every edge. Primarily because it would create confusion with where you are like you described